# Average 2-D plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have this 2-D plot in MATLAB.

[image]

I would like to get the average plot, something like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: You must have the data, don't you? Why don't you just take the average and plot it with a thicker line?

Comment: How can I do that?
I could do the average with respect to the y-axis, but then, in the areas where the plot is almost horizontal (600 < y < 700), I would have very few points. Thanks.

Comment: Please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is another example of plot that I would like to average: http://imgur.com/e59SZsX.

Comment: How do you expect anyone would be able to help you by posting plots? You need to post data and code, i.e. an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is not without reason I suggested that. I'll be surprised if you get any useful answers as the question is at the moment.

Comment: if you have the _Curve Fitting Toolbox_, you can use `ys=smooth(x,y,0.1)`. Vary the value `0.1` until the result suits you. [`smooth` documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose every line has the samen number of data points and x is to the right and y upwards...
If you turn your head 90 degrees to the left, every blue line is a function x with argument y. 
In that case, for every y-value, there is only one possible value for x. 
For every value of y you can sum the values for all blue lines and divide it by the number of blue lines, then you have your averaged, black value.

So look carefully if you can implement your data in such a way.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I can't. This is just a special case.
Not always x = f(y), and the data has not the same lenght.
See here: http://imgur.com/e59SZsX

Comment: muuhhhh, that is not funny XD
do you want a high accuracy or just a nice graphical presentation?
Otherwise, you may try to look for example between value y1 en y2... Check all data vectors if they have a y-value in between those values. Sum the corresponding x-values, en divide by the number of x-contributions you found.
The you created a x=f(y)...
depending on the required accuracy you can choose and wide or small interval voor y1 en y2!